# Get name of the enum in scala 3?

Tags: scala, enumeration, scala-3

Java enum has `name()` method but scala 3 doesn't have it.

How to get name of the enum in scala 3?

```scala
enum Color:
  case Red, Green, Blue
```

Answer (score 3):

`toString()` method gives the name of the enum.

```scala
enum Color:
  case Red, Blue, Yellow

println(Color.Red.toString()) //=> Red
```

Scala 3 enum can also extend java Enum class and use the `name()` method.

```scala
enum Color extends Enum[Color]:
  case Red, Blue, Yellow

println(Color.Red.name()) //=> Red
```

Comment: I guess both methods don't work with a `case Complicated(r: Int, g:Int, b:Int)`. In these cases `.productPrefix` gives you the name of the case (`Complicated` here).

Comment: @Thilo, it works for parameterized enums. https://scastie.scala-lang.org/mk8J7S8eTG2p0Yt1EuEXaw
Can you add some more detail about your example `case Complicated(r: Int, g:Int, b:Int)`?

Comment: The `enum` keyword can also be used to define Algebraic Data Types, which do not directly translate into Java enums: https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/enums/adts.html